# How do I setup an encrypted swap file?

Tags: encryption, swap

When I installed Ubuntu, I setup an encrypted home partition. Now I have come to an issue where I am running out of memory because I haven't setup swap. How can I setup an encrypted swap **file**?

A couple of times while booting I've seen some reference to cryptswap. I've also got these lines contained in `/etc/fstab`

```
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=1ba8a53b-1842-4de7-8e38-2d6c79f3a1ab none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: In newer ubuntu-versions (tested 14.10). You have to run /etc/init.d/cryptdisks-early reload @Adam Ryczkowski could you post your startup script?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to this [guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160504140513/http://hydra.geht.net/tino/howto/linux/cryptswap/) I set up an encrypted swap file (can't be used for hibernation). On Debian based distributions, you will need the `cryptsetup` package for these instructions.

1. Firstly create an appropriately sized file (here 4 gigabytes) to store the swap data:

   ```
   fallocate -l 4G /cryptswap
   ```
2. Add the following to `/etc/crypttab`:

   ```
   cryptswap /cryptswap /dev/urandom swap
   ```
3. Activate the newly created encrypted drive:

   ```
   service cryptdisks reload
   ```
4. Add the following to `/etc/fstab`:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/cryptswap none swap sw 0 0
   ```
5. Activate the new swap file:

   ```
   swapon -a
   ```

Comment: This encrypted swap is the only secure option for hibernation. With a little change to `/etc/crypttab` and a startup script (to ask user for mount password)

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski if you're around, another user was asking for that startup script, if you made one. See comment on the question.

Comment: @muru On Ubuntu 14.04 there is no need for such script. If I recall correctly, the early booting scripts parse the /etc/crypttab for a line like `cryptswap   /dev/sda5   none   luks` and asks the user for a password autmatically

Comment: Instead of truncate use **fallocate** to allocate inode to file; the mkswap step is **useless** as it is overwritten later when encrypted swap is setup.

Comment: @adam-ryczkowski, you say „only secure option for hibernation“, liamzebedee says „can't be used for hibernation“. Which one of you is right, resp. what further steps would it take to make it fit for hibernation?

Comment: @FrankN. Hibernation data live in swap, so it must be **decrypted** during early stage of boot. Decryption will work, if the swap is encrypted with a constant password. Then, during bootup phase, computer will ask for a password to decrypt swap - regardless whether there is a hibernation state on the swap or not. What liamzebedee showed does not use constant password, so will not work with hibernation (you will hibernate and power off, but will not be able to put correct password to read the hibernation state on waking up)

Comment: Nice summary. However, anyone wanting to read more will find that your link "this [guide](http://hydra.geht.net/tino/howto/linux/cryptswap/)" is dead.

Comment: Just a note: I had to reboot the system before the `/dev/mapper/cryptswap` volume appeared.

Comment: I followed the instructions exactly, apart from giving 8G argument to fallocate: `fallocate -l 8G /cryptswap`. However, the final encrypted swap memory created according to both `swapon -s` and `free -h` seems to be 4G still. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Skip the reboot:

```
sudo cryptdisks_start cryptswap
```

where `cryptswap` is the name in `/etc/crypttab`

Comment: I don't understand how that addresses the question. Could you please explain? As far as I understand it, OP wants to know how to set up (encrypted) swap space properly. Your answer just describes how to start a previously defined encrypted volume but not how to use it for swapping. -1

Comment: rise, o ancient thread. Friendly is trying to address what HRJ mentioned as a comment added to the OP. Namely, "I had to reboot the system before `/dev/mapper/cryptswap` volume appeared." This handy `cryptdisks_start swap0` (in my case) saved me from having to reboot. noice.