# How to resize disc after permanently disabling swap

Tags: partitioning, ssd, swap

My computer has 16GB of RAM and only 32GB of memory on SSD drive so I want to get rid of those 16GB of swap that was automatically created.

I have succesfully disabled swap memory following [How do I disable swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214805/how-do-i-disable-swap) and by disabling it in `/etc/fstab`.

Now I would like to resize my disc in order to use memory I released.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the swap partition, use GParted.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.

On Live desktop open GParted - delete the swap partition.
Grow the Ubuntu partition, just add the unallocated space.