# resizing ubuntu root parittion

Tags: gparted, disk, partitioning, fdisk

I want to expand /dev/sda5 partition but the unallocated space that can be used for expanding is not in ubuntu installation  partition table. is there any way to move unallocated space to this partition table? or any other way to expand /dev/sda5?

[image]

Comment: You will need to remove the one in between 1st (swap) Example on how to do this: http://askubuntu.com/a/214806/15811 (you also need the /etc/fstab edit in comments ;) )

Comment: I've deleted swap partition, now I have two separate unallocated space, only 4 GB freed swap space can be used for expand.

Comment: You have to increase the size of the extended partition `sda2` first. `sda2` is like a container, and `sda5` is in the container.