# Unable to unmount partition from live USB

Tags: mount

I'm trying to restore my Ubuntu following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem).

I launched from Live USB and `fdisk -l` gives me this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D9704AB0-61E0-44CF-BE30-B9C95522AD76

Device        Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048  15624191  15622144  7.5G Linux swap
/dev/sda2  15624192  64452607  48828416 23.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  64452608  64647167    194560   95M EFI System
/dev/sda4  64647168 234440703 169793536   81G Linux filesystem
```

But when I execute

```
root@ubuntu:~# umount /dev/sda1
```

I'm getting `umount: /dev/sda1: not mounted`

Comment: According to `fdisk`'s output `/dev/sda1` is your swap partition. As those are not mounted by default `umount`'s behaviour is expected and totally fine. What do you want to achieve? Maybe this helps: [How do I disable swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214805/how-do-i-disable-swap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214805/how-do-i-disable-swap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/dev/sda1 is apparently your swap partition. A swap partition doesn't get "mounted" so, as `unmount` is correctly telling you above: "/dev/sda1: not mounted".

Maybe you want to issue a `mount` on the command line, to see what *is* mounted.