# How can i reverse a Linux swap partition bact to a ntfs? (with loosing data)

Tags: partitioning

I have this partition:

1. 50gb of NTFS (luckily i saved all data in that 50gb)
2. 1.9 TB of Linux Swap (i think is empty)
3. 50gb where is linux

I need to recover that 1.9 TB with a quick method even if it makes you lose the data inside because in theory it is empty.

ty for helps

Comment: _“in theory it is empty.”_ The swap partition only contains useful data when the OS using it is running. It is “empty” if you turn off the OS or [disable using the swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214805/how-do-i-disable-swap) while it’s running.

Comment: You can use a [swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/a/796997).  2TB of swap partition is... insane...

Answer (score 2):

I generally assign about half of my RAM to a swap partition. This used to be recommended at least. So for my 8GB RAM on my desktop, I created a 4 GB swap.

As you've seen, yours is a little too big (!).

You can delete or resize the swap partition using the graphical program `gparted`. You might need to install it with `sudo apt install gparted` first.

There shouldn't be any "useful" i.e. user data in swap, it is a system partition.

Comment: I think you need to disable swap first (as @Melebius hinted), then unmount the swap partition, before you can get at it with `gparted`.